# 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' An uncatchable exception of type,Emgu.CV.World.dl loccurred in File '{0}' not found

Tags: c#, file, opencv, dll, emgucv

//Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using FaceRecognition;
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        FaceRec faceRec = new FaceRec();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            faceRec.openCamera(pbCamera, pbCaptured);
        }
    }
}
```

when i start this codes,i get this error System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'File '{0}' not found'
how can i solve this?

I checked the location of the dll file and it is in the right place.
I updated emgucv.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.